# Azure function CRUD on Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

How can we do CRUD with table storage in Azure functions:

I have insert working, but would like to know how to return entities and do updates and deletes too.

```
   public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, IAsyncCollector<User> outputTable)
    {
        log.Info($"C# HTTP trigger function processed a request. RequestUri={req.RequestUri}");

        var user = new User();
        user.PartitionKey = "Users";
        user.RowKey = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        user.UserId = "aaaa";

        user.Country = "uk";
        await outputTable.AddAsync(user);

....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind your function to an instance of `CloudTable` class, and then you get all its API at your hands.

I think you should be able to just replace `IAsyncCollector<User>` with `CloudTable` in your function definition and adjust the usage (provided you have a valid output binding).

See "Output usage" under [Azure Functions Storage table bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table).

Comment: yes, think that works now when using CloudTable and CRUD like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables